# Bep20 parse error reflection function

Tags: solidity, blockchain, tokens, contract-design, contract-deployment

Hi hi got this parse error in my contract could anybody help me to solve it? thanks a lot :)
don't mind about token name and token symbol :)

[image: Error]

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;

interface IBEP20 {
  function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

  function decimals() external view returns (uint8);

  function symbol() external view returns (string memory);

  function name() external view returns (string memory);

  function getOwner() external view returns (address);

  function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

  function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

  function allowance(address _owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

  function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
 
  function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

contract Context {
  constructor () internal { }

  function _msgSender() internal view returns (address payable) {
    return msg.sender;
  }

  function _msgData() internal view returns (bytes memory) {
    this;
    return msg.data;
  }
}

library SafeMath {
  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");

    return c;
  }

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    return sub(a, b, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
  }

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    require(b <= a, errorMessage);
    uint256 c = a - b;

    return c;
  }

  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    if (a == 0) {
      return 0;
    }

    uint256 c = a * b;
    require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");

    return c;
  }

  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    return div(a, b, "SafeMath: division by zero");
  }

  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    require(b > 0, errorMessage);
    uint256 c = a / b;

    return c;
  }

  function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    return mod(a, b, "SafeMath: modulo by zero");
  }

  function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    require(b != 0, errorMessage);
    return a % b;
  }
}

contract Ownable is Context {
  address private _owner;

  event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

  constructor () internal {
    address msgSender = _msgSender();
    _owner = msgSender;
    emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), msgSender);
  }

  function owner() public view returns (address) {
    return _owner;
  }

  modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(_owner == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
    _;
  }

  function renounceOwnership() public onlyOwner {
    emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
    _owner = address(0);
  }

  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
    _transferOwnership(newOwner);
  }

  function _transferOwnership(address newOwner) internal {
    require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
    emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, newOwner);
    _owner = newOwner;
  }
}

contract X is Context, IBEP20, Ownable {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  mapping (address => uint256) private _balances;

  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;

  uint256 private _totalSupply;
  uint8 public _decimals;
  string public _symbol;
  string public _name;

  constructor() public {
    _name = “x”;
    _symbol = “Y”;
    _decimals = 18;
    _totalSupply = 666666000000000000000000000000;
    _balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;

    emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
  }

  function getOwner() external view returns (address) {
    return owner();
  }

  function decimals() external view returns (uint8) {
    return _decimals;
  }

  function symbol() external view returns (string memory) {
    return _symbol;
  }

  function name() external view returns (string memory) {
    return _name;
  }

  function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256) {
    return _totalSupply;
  }

  function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256) {
    return _balances[account];
  }

  function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool) {
    _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
    return true;
  }

  function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256) {
    return _allowances[owner][spender];
  }

  function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool) {
    _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
    return true;
  }

  function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool) {
    _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "BEP20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
    return true;
  }

  function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public returns (bool) {
    _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].add(addedValue));
    return true;
  }

  
  function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public returns (bool) {
    _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].sub(subtractedValue, "BEP20: decreased allowance below zero"));
    return true;
  }

  function mint(uint256 amount) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
    _mint(_msgSender(), amount);
    return true;
  }

  function burn(uint256 amount) public returns (bool) {
    _burn(_msgSender(), amount);
    return true;
  }

  function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal {
    require(sender != address(0), "BEP20: transfer from the zero address");
    require(recipient != address(0), "BEP20: transfer to the zero address");

    _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, "BEP20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
    _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
    emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
  }

  function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal {
    require(account != address(0), "BEP20: mint to the zero address");

    _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(amount);
    _balances[account] = _balances[account].add(amount);
    emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount);
  }

  function _burn(address account, uint256 amount) internal {
    require(account != address(0), "BEP20: burn from the zero address");

    _balances[account] = _balances[account].sub(amount, "BEP20: burn amount exceeds balance");
    _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(amount);
    emit Transfer(account, address(0), amount);
  }

  function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) internal {
    require(owner != address(0), "BEP20: approve from the zero address");
    require(spender != address(0), "BEP20: approve to the zero address");

    _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
    emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
  }

  function _burnFrom(address account, uint256 amount) internal {
    _burn(account, amount);
    _approve(account, _msgSender(), _allowances[account][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "BEP20: burn amount exceeds allowance"));
  }

 function reflectionFromToken(uint256 tAmount, bool deductTransferFee) public view returns(uint256) {
      require(tAmount <= _tTotal, "Amount must be less than supply");
      if (!deductTransferFee) {
          (uint256 rAmount,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
          return rAmount;
        } else {
            (,uint256 rTransferAmount,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
            return rTransferAmount;
        }
    
 
    function tokenFromReflection(uint256 rAmount) public view returns(uint256) {
        require(rAmount <= _rTotal, "Amount must be less than total reflections");
        uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
        return rAmount.div(currentRate);
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide more details, like what is the parser error exactly, in which line is it, and can you format the code a bit better?

Comment: sorry for that, line 275, i can directly send you the code?

Comment: @Zero_ykmusic The error is that the previous function is missing a `}` to close it. Unfortunately once fixing that line the contract has other issues.